# Where are the Joomla tests located, and how can I include them in my CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: php, joomla-4.x, docker, unit-testing

I am trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline for a Joomla project and would like to include tests for my Joomla components. I am looking for the location of the Joomla tests and how I can integrate them into my pipeline.

Here is the current configuration of my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:20.10.7
  services:
    - docker:20.10.7-dind
  script:
    - docker pull joomla:4-php8.0-apache

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker run --rm my-joomla4-image /bin/bash -c "php /path/to/joomla-tests/component/ComponentInitializationTest.php"

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - // commands to deploy the Joomla4 site to your desired environment
```

In particular, I would like to know:

Where can I find the Joomla tests?
What is the directory structure for the tests?
How can I integrate the Joomla tests into the test stage of my CI/CD pipeline?
Are there any additional configurations or dependencies required to run the Joomla tests?
Any guidance on how to locate and include the Joomla tests in my pipeline would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!